# How to cut last digits from number - REGEX

Tags: regex

I have to find the first 11 digits and cut everything that follows from the eleventh digit.

I've been trying to do it with this pattern `:/^(\d{11}.*?)`. However, doesn't work.

You know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example of your input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your regex flavour, you could use:

- Find: `^\d{11}\K.+$`
- Replace: `NOTHING`

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  \d{11}    : 11 digits
  \K        : forget all we have seen until this position
  .+        : 1 or more any character
$           : end of line
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match first characters, you need to use anchor `^` that will anchor match at the beginning of the string.

If you want to match something and then reuse it, then you need to capture it isnide capturing group and use it in sbstitution with `\1`.

If you want to capture eleven digits - `\d{11}` will work for you.

So to sum up, you need pattern `^(\d{11}).*` and replace with `\1`. `.*` will match 0 or more characters (any).

Comment: That's right and works, however, I actually want those 11 numbers to be there.. I worked out the right pattern eventually.

Comment: @Turpan If it works and helped you, you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trying, It actually works with this one:

```
^(?=(\d{11})).+?
```